# ./configure && make install failed

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, configure, autotools, pkg-config

Good Morning
While i'm installing RabbitMQ libraries, I found a problem:

```
autoreconf -i && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

But ./configure stop at this position:

```
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
./configure: line 11104: syntax error near unexpected token `0.17'
./configure: line 11104: `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG(0.17)'
```

Comment: Bah, I totally disagree that this is off-topic... linux package configuration is extremely non-trivial and not at all a user-level exercise. This is precisely related to "software tools commonly used by programmers."

Answer (score 12):

your autotools project uses `pkg-config`, but it seems that you either don't have that installed at all or you are lacking the "pkg-config <-> autotools" glue (`pkg.m4`), which provides the `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG` macro.

if this is true, then the `autoreconf -i` should have complained when recreating `configure` (though probably only as a non-fatal warning) -> check your build-logs.

you should be able to fix this by installing `pkg-config`

**NOTE**: generally, if you get an error it's good to break down the problem into sub-problems. since you are really calling four different tasks (`autoreconf`, `./configure` and `make` and `sudo make install`), you might want to execute them one by one and see where it actually fails (in your case: the 2nd tasks), and what the prior steps indicated (the autoreconf-call).